# FParsec and postfix modifiers to parsed items

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

As an exercise for myself I'm using FParsec to write a function that can generate a random string from a spec in (limited) Regex form.

E.g.

```
Input: ([Hh]ello ){1,3} world!?
Output: Hello hello world!

Input: (\d{1,2}\.){3}(\d{1,2})
Output: 38.12.29.05
```

I have a lot of it working, but I'm having trouble with the idea of postfix terms (i.e. that a parser might need to go back and modify the output, not just the position in the Char stream). E.g. "a" vs "a+"

Here's a cut-down version of my domain types:

```
type Count =
    | ExactCount of int
    | MinCount of int
    | MaxCount of int
    | RangeCount of int * int

type Term =
    | CharLiteral of char
    | Count of Term * Count

type RandExpSpec = Term list
```

So the input `ab` should generate `[CharLiteral 'a'; CharLiteral 'b']` but `ab+` should generate `[CharLiteral 'a'; Count (CharLiteral 'b', MinCount 1)]`. So that kind of implies that, on encountering a `Count` term in the stream, the parser needs to backtrack through the output in order to wrap the last term in another object.

Now, I don't know how to do that. Here's my current parsing definition, that does (mostly) work but is very inefficient:

```
let parseCharLiteral = choice [ letter; digit ] |>> CharLiteral

let rec parseTerm =
    parse.Delay(fun () -> choice [ parseCharLiteral ])

and parseCount =
    parseTerm
    .>>. choice [ skipChar '*' >>% (MinCount 0)
                  skipChar '+' >>% (MinCount 1)
                  skipChar '?' >>% (RangeCount(0, 1)) ]
    |>> Count

let parseTerms =
    many ((attempt parseCount) <|> parseTerm) .>> eof
```

You can see that in `parseCount` I call `parseTerm` first, then parse the actual count information. Then, in `parseTerms` I attempt the `parseCount` parser every time, backtracking through the *input* if it doesn't work. This is very inefficient because I'm essentially making two passes on almost every char in the input stream just in case it's followed by a count modifier.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I feel like I should be writing something more like:

```
let parseCharLiteral = choice [ letter; digit ] |>> CharLiteral

let rec parseTerm =
    parse.Delay(fun () -> choice [ parseCharLiteral ] .>>. (attempt parseCount))

and parseCount =
    choice [ skipChar '*' >>% (MinCount 0)
             skipChar '+' >>% (MinCount 1)
             skipChar '?' >>% (RangeCount(0, 1)) ]
    |>> Count

let parseTerms =
    many parseTerm .>> eof
```

but I can't make that work since `parseCount` qould need to wrap the previous term returned by `parseTerm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `opt` to allow `parseCount` to not find a count if there isn't one:

```ml
let parseCount =
    parseTerm
    .>>. opt (choice [ skipChar '*' >>% (MinCount 0)
                       skipChar '+' >>% (MinCount 1)
                       skipChar '?' >>% (RangeCount(0, 1)) ])
    |>> function
    | term, None -> term
    | term, Some count -> Count (term, count)

let parseTerms =
    many parseCount .>> eof
```